# How to fail a TFS build based on Fortify scan results

Tags: build, fortify

From a PowerShell query, how can I get the count of new critical or high vulnerabilities from a Fortify security scan of .NET code? The query should not include any findings already on the SSC server that were documented as "not an issue" or "suppressed".

We have Team Foundation Server 2017u2. As part of our build and release process we execute HP/Micro Focus Fortify security scans and upload the results to the Fortify SSC server. We are trying to make the build/release fail whenever the scanner detects new critical or high findings in the code. We use the Micro Focus Fortify plugin for TFS to configure the scan step and upload to SSC: ([Fortify TFS plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fortifyvsts.hpe-security-fortify-vsts#overview)). We added a PowerShell task afterward to attempt to query for findings and fail the build if needed.

The examples and suggestions we've found use the FPRUtility to query the .fpr file generated from our current scan. However, this current scan does not include any previously entered content from developers documenting false positives or suppressed issues. This results in our builds always failing.

I tried looking through the REST API docs but, while Swagger makes it easy to see the parameters and contracts, I can't find any good documentation stating what all the different controllers are or how I need to orchestrate a series of calls to get the data I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer I needed. After the scan and upload to SSC completes, you call the issues REST API from your PowerShell script in this format:

```
[host:port]/ssc/api/v1/projectVersions/[versionid]/issues?q=[fortify+priority+order]:high+OR+[fortify+priority+order]:critical&qm=issues
```

So a simplified PowerShell script to do this in a TFS build step looks like:

```
    $jsonResults  = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri "https://{host:port}/ssc/api/v1/projectVersions/{projectVersionNumberHere}/issues?q=[fortify+priority+order]:high+OR+[fortify+priority+order]:critical&qm=issues" 
    $undocumentedFindings = $jsonResults.data | where {$_.primaryTag -eq $null}
    if ($undocumentedFindings.Count -gt 0)
    {
        Write-Error "Fortify detected $undocumentedFindings.Count undocumented critical and high vulnerabilities. These findings must be remediated or documented before the build can continue."
    }
```

Comment: This api returns aggregated result for all scans, how can we get scan results for only the last scan ?